# Setting SqlDataSource properties in OnInit versus PageLoad

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I would like to move some SQL code from the aspx page to the code behind page. The SQL code is bound to a `DataSource` object.

I am unsure whether to add this code to `OnInit`, or to `PageLoad`. Does it matter which one, or is there a better place to put it than another? I would think `OnInit` would make more sense since I am binding the Select/Update commands and parameters prior to actually using them with an active connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Init is better. This is where control properties are set anyway so you will get the closest thing to setting them in markup. On a side note my advice is that you move to ObjectDataSource and extract the Data Access code from your code behind as well. Your markup + code behind are equivalent to the View in MVC terms and data access code does not belong there. If you are doing serious refactoring it may be worth looking into the MVP pattern. With this pattern you get MVC equivalent separation of concerns and testability with Web Forms. In fact MVP is a kind of MVC pattern.